# How to write testmethod for geopointe.actionHandler

Tags: unit-test, actionfunction

I have a few classes written that implements Geopointe's action handler, but I don't know how to go about writing a test class for them. All I can find are test classes written for the schedulable class. Below is one of my classes. Any help in writing this test class would be greatly appreciated. I don't even know where to start.

```
global class GP_LunchAndLearnAction implements geopointe.ActionHandler 
{
  public geopointe.ActionResponse execute(geopointe.ActionRequest req) 
  {

    Id[] affilIds = new List<Id>();

    //Construct an actionResponse object for the map page
    //
    geopointe.ActionResponse res = new geopointe.ActionResponse();

    res.responseAction = geopointe.ActionResponse.ResponseAction.REDIRECT_NEWWINDOW;

    affilIds.addAll(req.objectNameRecordIdsMap.get('account_to_contact_affiliation__c'));

    // Get the Account and Provider info
    Account_to_Contact_Affiliation__c[] affil = 
    [
    SELECT Id,Account__c,Provider_Is_Lead__c,Provider_Contact__c,Provider_Account_Id__c
    FROM Account_to_Contact_Affiliation__c 
    WHERE Id =: affilIds[0]
    ];      

    // Build the URL
    //
    String callUrl = '';

    callUrl += 'https://na15.salesforce.com/00U/e';
    callUrl += '?what_id=' + affil[0].Account__c;
    callUrl += '&who_id=' + affil[0].Provider_Contact__c;
    callUrl += '&retURL=/' + affil[0].Account__c;

    // Assign the url and return
    res.url = callUrl;

    return res;         
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: Thanks to @crop1645, I was able to write the following method:**

```
@isTest static void test_LunchAndLearnAction() 
{
    geopointe.ActionRequest req = new geopointe.ActionRequest();

    String instance = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().getHost().split('\\.')[1];  

    Set<Id> insertedAffilIds = new Set<Id>();

    // Get affiliations created in @testSetup method
    Account_to_Contact_Affiliation__c[] affils = new List<Account_to_Contact_Affiliation__c>(
        [SELECT Id, Account__c, Provider_Account_Id__c, Provider_Contact__c FROM Account_to_Contact_Affiliation__c]
        );

    for(Account_to_Contact_Affiliation__c af : affils)
    {
        insertedAffilIds.add(af.Id);
    }

    // Set object map
    //
    req.objectNameRecordIdsMap = new Map<String,Set<Id>>();
    req.objectNameRecordIdsMap.put('account_to_contact_affiliation__c', insertedAffilIds);

    GP_LunchAndLearnAction lla = new GP_LunchAndLearnAction();
    geopointe.ActionResponse res = lla.execute(req);

    // Build the expected URL
    //
    String callUrl = '';

    callUrl += 'https://' + instance + '.salesforce.com/00U/e'; 
    callUrl += '?what_id=' + affils[0].Account__c;
    callUrl += '&who_id=' + affils[0].Provider_Contact__c;
    callUrl += '&retURL=/' + affils[0].Account__c;

    System.assertEquals(callUrl, res.url);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't worked explicitly with this appexchange product, testing your handler would be straightforward

```
@isTest
private static testmethod testMyActionHandler() {
   // mock some Account_to_Contact_Affiliation__c sobjects (construct/insert)

   GP_LunchAndLearnAction ah = new GP_LunchAndLearnAction();
   geopointe.ActionRequest req = new geopointe.ActionRequest();
   // simulate a request - see variables in
   // http://help.arrowpointe.com/customer/portal/articles/1809592-actions
   req.batchNumber = 1;
   ... populate remaining fields in req
   geopointe.ActionResponse res = ah.execute(req);
   System.assertEquals(yourexpectedVal, res.url);
   ... other asserts
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I'm going to try this first thing Monday and let you know the results. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect @crop1645! I've edited my original post to include the final method.